# GLib-CRITICAL error using GHashTable

Tags: c, hashtable, glib

I'm attempting to use GLib to create a way to cache a function output for future fast calculations. Here is an example of the implementation I'm using...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <math.h>

static GHashTable *table;

double P_l(double x,int lmax){
  //double pl;
  double p[lmax+2];
  int l;

  p[0] = 1.;
  p[1] = x;
  for (l = 1; l < lmax; ++l)
  {
    p[l+1] = ((2.*l+1.)*x*p[l]-l*p[l-1])/(l+1.);
  }
 //printf("cost = %E, l = %i, Pl = %E\n", x, lmax, p[lmax]);
  return p[lmax];
}


double cached_P_l(double x,
                                int l
                                ) {
  gchar *key;
  gchar *value;
  key = g_new (gchar, 1);
  value = g_new (gchar, 1);
  double answer;
  sprintf(key,"%d %i", x,l);
    if(g_hash_table_lookup(table, g_strdup (key)) == NULL){

    answer = P_l(x,l);
        printf("NOT FOUND IN LIST \n");
    sprintf(value, "%f", answer);
    g_hash_table_insert (table, g_strdup (key), g_strdup (value));
    }
    else{
        printf("FOUND IN LIST \n");
        printf("VALUE: %f \n",atof(g_hash_table_lookup(table, g_strdup (key))));

}
}

int main(){

  GHashTable* table = g_hash_table_new_full (g_str_hash, g_str_equal, g_free, g_free);

  double x=1.;
  int l =2;
  cached_P_l(x,l);
  l=3;
  cached_P_l(x,l);
  cached_P_l(x,l);

  return 0;
}
```

The code compiled fine, but when I run the code I get the following cryptic (to me at least) error:

```
(process:32996): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
NOT FOUND IN LIST 

(process:32996): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_insert_internal: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed

(process:32996): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_lookup: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
NOT FOUND IN LIST 

(process:32996): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_insert_internal: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
```

Comment: It seems you have a global `GHashTable *table` and a local one which is contained in the main function

Comment: Every time you call `g_strdup (key)` or `g_strdup (value)` and fail to preserve a pointer to the starting address for the block of memory allocated, you create a *memory leak*.

Comment: How would one go about preserving the pointer to the starting address in this context?

Comment: You only need `g_strdup` passing to `g_hash_table_insert` (it will store the pointer and free the memory when the hash table is freed), for `g_hash_table_lookup`, you can simply pass `key` (the lookup will be preformed on the value passed and there is no need to allocate memory and permanently store a copy). Your larger problems are due to passing invalid parameters. (you are not passing pointers where required) See [**Hash Tables**](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html)

Comment: Specifically `key = g_new (gchar, 1);` and `value = g_new (gchar, 1);` create `gpointer` type cast to `gchar` allocating `1` char (or `gchar`). That isn't adequate storage for a `string` (*nul-terminated* array of chars) you attempt to create with e.g. `sprintf(key,"%d %i", x,l);` (not to mention to standard C/glib mix/match) Take a look at [**g_sprintf ()**](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-sprintf)